# Updating database in Laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blade for a car sale system contains selections form inputs. I am trying to insert what is selected from the drop down selection but i get an error i do not know why.

```
 <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group-lg col-md-4">
     <label>MAKE</label>
     <select  name="model" class="form-control"  required autofocus >
     <option selected>choose...</option>
     <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
     <option  value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
     </select>

     </div>
```

How can i insert the above selected item using eloquent in laravel

Comment: whats the error?? show us your controller code with error

Answer (score 0):

You have to show us the error response so we can know what happens on your code...

BTW, you can make some basic check:

1. have you insert csrf_field() in you form?
2. the request method is post or get? and set correctly?

Comment: yah csrf_field() is included and am using post . I am asking for the eloquent command to update the database when one item is selected

Comment: No idea with what you are talking about, more details plz(reproduce steps, use case, error message...) @DENNISKITHINJI

Answer (score 0):

First open a form, route it to Controller method.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'TestController@test', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
  <div class="form-group">
  <h3>Pick a car</h3>
  {{ Form::select('carModel', [
    'Toyota' => 'Toyota',
    'Mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
    'Subaru' => 'Subaru']
  ) }}
  {!! Form::submit('submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In controller access it like this

```
class TestController extends Controller {

   public function test(Request $request)
   {
       $carModel = $request->get('carModel');
   }
}
```

Comment: can i use basic html form and still use                                                 class TestController extends Controller {

   public function test(Request $request)
   {
       $carModel = $request->get('carModel');
   }
}

Comment: You can use basic HTML, you can use Laravel Collective HTML and FORMs too. 
You have to "route" your form to Controller  - create HTML form, add action, e.g., `<form method="post" action="{{ route('routeName') }}">`, but don't forget to add `csrf_field()` in form. 
In routes (web.php) add named route, which points to controller : 
    `Route::post('post_url', 'ControllerName@method')->('routeName');`
and retrieve $request data on Controller. 

For more info, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests